# What event handlers are attached to a DOM node - how to find?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Is there a way to find what event handlers are attached to a given DOM node?

For example, when you click the "add comment" link, there's an event handler attached to it which shows the comment form. Now, if I have a DOM document (a web page), and want to list all the event handlers for one specific node, is there a way to do this?

(I suspect that it's not possible for JS running within the page; do browser extensions in FF have access to this data?)

Comment: Take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Comment: @McStretch: Useful, thank you. Didn't find that before, voting to close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome (and I suspect Safari) can show attached event listeners when you select an element in the DOM and then scroll down the right sidebar to the Event Listeners section. There, you can see which functions are attached.

I don't have a copy of Firebug at the moment, but I suspect the DOM tab to show similar information in Firefox as well.

Comment: Indeed there is, thank you (in Chrome that is, FBug 1.6 doesn't have it).

Comment: @Piskvor: Firebug has an extension called [Eventbug](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/eventbug-alpha-released/) which provides similar functionality.

Comment: @Erik Hesselink: Thank you, that looks useful!

Answer (score 9):

In Chrome, you can use [`getEventListeners`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject).

1. Open Developer Tools
2. Select the element you're interested in
3. Type this the console: `getEventListeners($0)`
4. Hit enter.

An object mapping event names to their handlers should be returned.  Note that `$0` is a [special dev tools variable](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#0_-_4) which always points to the last element selected in the "Elements" tabs.

Comment: The response differs from what Event Listeners tab display. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome:

1. "Inspect Element" on the element you want to know about
2. In the "Elements" tab in developer tools, in the right-hand pane, click on "Event Listeners"

This will show you what event handlers are attached to that element.

(Krof's answer could have been more clearly written.)